# Determine when $(p-1)/(k+1)$ is integer for prime $p$ and $k \in \left\{{0,1,\cdots,\left\lfloor{(1/2)(3-\sqrt{5})\, p}\right\rfloor-1}\right\}$

Tags: prime-numbers

Obviously this holds for $k = 0$ and $k = 1$ sine $p - 1$ is even.  The limit on $k$ is about $0.38 p$.  This limit is due to the problem details however a general solution if possible for $k \le p - 2$ is just as good.

Comment: This question is very confusing - the ratio is rational for _all_ prime $p$ and positive $k$. Do you mean to ask whether it's integral? Are you looking for a method to determine when the result is integral ('divide them out'), or a way of counting the number of solutions (which will vary quite a bit), or what? What's the source of the upper bound on $k$?

Comment: Yes when is this integral and when it is rational.  For example when $p = 13$ then $p - 1$ is 12 and is divisible when $k = 0, 1, 2, 3, 5$ which covers the maximum values of $k = 4$.  When $p = 11$ then we have $10/(k+1)$ which is divisible when $k = 0, 1$ but not when $k = 2, 3$ which covers all the cases due to the ${k}_{max}$ limit.

Comment: The source of the upper bound on $k$ is from counting the number of factorable quadratics of the form ${p}^{2}\, {x}^{2} + s\, x + t = \left({p\, x + a}\right) \left({p\, x + b}\right)$ where $- N \le s, t \le + N$ for height $N \ge {p}^{2}$.  There are correction terms to this sum which is the souce of the $k$ bound.

Comment: Lorenz, please look at the title you typed. It says rational.

Comment: I assume you want the set/floor in the title to contain $p$ somehow? Right now it reads "$k \in 0$", since $\lfloor \rm that\ thing \rfloor = 0$.